# Update record using Core Data in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I can't seem to find an example of how to update an existing row of data using Core Data on iOS. In terms of SQL, I'm looking to do something along the lines of:
UPDATE device SET attr1='blah', attr2='blah' WHERE deviceid='1';

I know I can do something like this:
[device setValue:@"blah" forKey:@"attr1"];

However, how can I do that only WHERE the deviceid='1'?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is a fatal mistake to think of Core Data in SQL terms. Core Data is an object graph management system that sometimes uses SQL to persist the object graph. In Core Data, entities are not tables, attributes are not columns, managedObjects are not rows. See the [Tequila advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350304/grouping-a-core-data-data-result/2350612#2350612)

Comment: +1 "entities are not tables, attributes are not columns, managedObjects are not rows"... that has a cool kinda zen ring to it.

Comment: This is not helpful for me. How about some code examples or links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `lastObject` method for safety reasons. If `executeFetchRequest:error:` returns nil, your program will crash:

```
NSManagedObject *device = [fetchedObjects lastObject];
```

Answer (score 13):

With Core Data, you never execute SQL queries directly... you update the database simply by updating the value of your object, and then saving the managedObjectContext.

In your example, device is a specific instance of an object... `[device setValue:@"blah" forKey:@"attr1"];` will only update that 1 device object, so you don't need any where clause.

If you need to retrieve the correct device object from the database, then you need to use a [NSFetchRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html). I recommend looking through the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) to get an understanding of how Core Data works. If you are asking about SQL statements and WHERE clauses, it seems you have an incorrect view of what Core Data is.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not SQL. But I'm having trouble setting values on the entity after doing a fetch request. For instance, I use the following code to do a fetchrequest:

Comment: // get device record
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
           entityForName:@"device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
 [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
 
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(deviceid = %d)", deviceidint];
 [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

Comment: But its giving me an error when i try to update a value on the entity like this:

Comment: [entity setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sealedSwitch.on] forKey:@"sealed"];

Comment: This is the most correct answer, it must be checked as an answer!